# Likelihood ratio test and formulate Pearson's

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Consider two simple random samples $X_1, . . . , X_n $ and $Y_1, . . . , Y_m$, where $X_i ∼ Poisson(µ_x),$
$Y_j ∼ Poisson(µ_y)$, whose elements $X_i$ and $Y_j$ are mutually independent for any indices
$i = 1, . . . , n$ and $j = 1, . . . , m$. Regarding the hypotheses $H_0 : µ_x = µ_y$ versus $H_1 : µ_x \neq µ_y$, how to obtain
the likelihood ratio test and formulate Pearson's chi-square test? Are these tests asymptotically equivalent?

Comment: Is one of the hypothesis supposed to be $\mu_x \neq \mu_y$?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.